# Ionic 5 email Reactive form validation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an odd question because I'm better in ionic but I'm stuck in a simple bug. I'm using the reactive form every validation is working fine email validation is working fine but there is a glitch. I tried very Regular expressions but still failed.

come to the point.

TS file.

```
initForm(courseId) {
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', [Validators.required]],
  full_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  email: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/), Validators.email]),],
  country: ['', [Validators.required]],
  city: ['', [Validators.required]],
  timezone: ['', [Validators.required]],
  job_title: ['', [Validators.required]],
  experience: ['', [Validators.required]],
  short_bio: ['', [Validators.required]],
  education: ['', [Validators.required]],
  mobile_no: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$')]],
  address: ['', [Validators.required]],
  courseid: [courseId]
 });
}
```

Html file

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <ion-list lines="full">
          <ion-item *ngIf="titles.length">
            <ion-label color="primary">
              Title
              <div class="invalid-question" *ngIf="isSubmit && !f.title.value">
                <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
              </div>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-select formControlName="title">
              <ion-select-option disabled value="">Select one</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let title of titles" [value]="title">{{title}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input 
              placeholder="Type here..." 
              formControlName="full_name" 
              type="text"
            ></ion-input>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.full_name.value) || (f.full_name.invalid && (f.full_name.dirty || f.full_name.touched))">
              <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input placeholder="Type here..." formControlName="email" type="text"></ion-input>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.email.value) || (f.email.invalid && (f.email.dirty || f.email.touched))">
              <!-- <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="!f.email.value">This field is required.</ion-text> -->
              <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="f.email.touched && f.email.errors?.email && f.email.hasError('pattern')">Please enter valid email address.</ion-text>
              <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="(f.email.touched || isSubmit) && f.email.errors?.required">This field is required.</ion-text>
              <!-- <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="f.email.value && f.email.invalid && !f.email.touched">Please enter valid email address.</ion-text> -->
            </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="allCountries.length">
            <ion-label color="primary">Country
              <div class="invalid-question" *ngIf="isSubmit && !f.country.value">
                <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
              </div>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-select formControlName="country" (ionChange)="getAllCities($event)">
              <ion-select-option disabled value="">Select one</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of allCountries" [value]="country">{{country}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="cities.length">
            <ion-label color="primary">City
              <div class="invalid-question" *ngIf="isSubmit && !f.city.value">
                <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
              </div>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-select placeholder="Select City" formControlName="city">
              <ion-select-option disabled value="">Select one</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">{{city}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="timeZon.length">
            <ion-label color="primary">
              Timezone
              <div class="invalid-question" *ngIf="isSubmit && !f.timezone.value">
                <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
              </div>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-select placeholder="Select Time Zone" formControlName="timezone">
              <ion-select-option disabled value="">Select one</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let zone of timeZon" [value]="zone">{{zone}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="form.get('city').value">
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Mobile No</ion-label>
            <div class="countryCode display-flex w-100">
              <ion-input class="code" [value]="countyCode" *ngIf="countyCode" type="tel" disabled></ion-input>
              <ion-input class="number" placeholder="Type here..." appIntegerInput formControlName="mobile_no" type="tel"></ion-input>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.mobile_no.value) || (f.mobile_no.invalid && (f.mobile_no.dirty || f.mobile_no.touched))">
              <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="!f.mobile_no.value">This field is required.</ion-text>
              <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="f.mobile_no.value && f.mobile_no.invalid">Please enter valid mobile number.</ion-text>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="educations.length">
            <ion-label color="primary">Education
              <div class="invalid-question" *ngIf="isSubmit && !f.education.value">
                <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
              </div>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-select color="primary" formControlName="education">
              <ion-select-option disabled value="">Select one</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let education of educations" [value]="education">{{education}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Job Title</ion-label>
            <ion-input placeholder="Type here..." formControlName="job_title" type="text"></ion-input>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.job_title.value) || (f.job_title.invalid && (f.job_title.dirty || f.job_title.touched))">
              <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Experience</ion-label>
            <ion-input placeholder="Type here..." formControlName="experience" type="text"></ion-input>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.experience.value) || (f.experience.invalid && (f.experience.dirty || f.experience.touched))">
              <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
            </div>
          </ion-item> 
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Short Bio</ion-label>
            <ion-textarea placeholder="Type here..." formControlName="short_bio" rows="3">
            </ion-textarea>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.short_bio.value) || (f.short_bio.invalid && (f.short_bio.dirty || f.short_bio.touched))">
              <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Address</ion-label>
            <ion-textarea placeholder="Type here..." formControlName="address" rows="3">
            </ion-textarea>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="(isSubmit && !f.address.value) || (f.address.invalid && (f.address.dirty || f.address.touched))">
              <ion-text color="danger">This field is required.</ion-text>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </form>
```

[image: This picture shows perfect error]

This picture shows perfect error

[image: When we add @gmail it's not showing the valid field]

When we add @gmail it's not showing the valid field

[image: After add dot it shows the error]

After add dot it shows the error

kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular email validator is just a regular expression check, I believe this is the RegExp for it:

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$
```

I imagine that applying your custom `.pattern` validator and the `.email` validator in combination would cause some collisions which may be undesirable.

I would suggest that you either use only the Angular `.email` validator if you are happy with `^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$`. If you want something custom, remove the Angular `.email` validator completely and handle all the checks through a custom RegExp validator (i.e. the `.pattern` that you have already started).

Comment: I tried everything but still all in vain. Thanks for your response

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this one ?

```
'^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$'
```

Comment: This is the same Regex as the one from last year.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31131955)

Comment: no it is not the same, look carefully

Comment: I did. This string compiles to the same RegExp.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/vygzPTMvMUfBVkE/LjpRt8pA11IvXlVbN1bbAcYFsmP0QJzYaiMdk1oVfa78kozUIqCWvNRyhaDUdNeKAg11fLpRtKtrcnEl5@cV5@ek6uXkp2vAnKBXkh9cUpSZl66hqWBra6sAtgRJUPP//7SixNxUAA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: not in ionic/angular, I just applied it this morning in an app upgrade and it works fine there.

Comment: Although the Stackblitz works a little different then the upgraded project, take a look here https://angular-awfcm7.stackblitz.io

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.